# How to change mailman defaults

Tags: mailman

we are using mailman in our company for very different things and we are creating a lot of lists all the time. What I'd like to do is to change the server wide defaults of mailman. For example I'd like to have my/our own welcome message in every new created list without changing it all the time manually. The same with the maximum length of the mail body current default for every new list is 40kB but I'd like to have 0 (unlimited).

Where can I find these configurations?

It will save a lot of time, because I do need to care all the time for this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu, you should modify /etc/mailman/en/subscribeack.txt. Note that this is a plain email with no styling at all.